# python Mechanize- Following a link

Tags: python, html, web, hyperlink, mechanize

I'm trying to follow a hyperlinked image on http://www.neopets.com/donations.phtml.

When I click the link on the normal page, it works. However, when I use my mechanize script or even when I copy the link and paste it into the toolbar, I get an error. Maybe this is a little broad, but does anyone have any explanation for this? What should I add to my script to fix this?

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.neopets.com/donations.phtml")

#login
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = 'username' 
br.form['password'] = 'password'
br.submit()

for link in br.links(url_regex="takedonation_new.phtml"):
    placeholder = 1

url = br.follow_link(link).geturl()
print br.response().read()
print link
```

Comment: give more description of the error (the traceback)

Comment: I get redirected to a neopets.com page that says I arrived there by mistake. I think it's something to do with the neopets website, and not mechanize, but I don't know how to bypass it.

Comment: The exact error is : "Error: You have been directed to this page from the wrong place! If you KEEP getting this error, chances are you have some security settings enabled that are not letting you play Neopets correctly."